# How to update currently playing protected video from iOS app when casting to Chromecast?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I checked [CastVideos-ios sample app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) and now using this code to switch current item when casting to Chromecast:

```
let builder = GCKMediaInformationBuilder(contentURL: url)
if let remoteMediaClient = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient {
    remoteMediaClient.loadMedia(with: builder.build())
}
```

It works [for the videos from this example](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/f.json), but I also need to play videos with FairPlay protection. How can I set `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` in such case? Or should I use another approach?